# How to edit the text field length in sitefinity campaign create issue form

Tags: sitefinity

[enter image description here][1]

As in the screenshot  I would like to change the length of input box of message subject , how should I approach , this is the default sitefinity text box when the issue is created.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity forms, or like the at /Sitefinity/Content/Forms/Forms?

When you edit the textbox widget there's usually a tabstrip or something at the top for options (limitations?) where you can set the size.